# How to configure Spring WS to produce SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws

I want my web service to produce messages according to SOAP 1.2 protocol. By default, Spring WS is configured for SOAP 1.1 protocol, and when I send message to my service, represented in SOAP 1.2, I get the exception:"incorrect content-type for SOAP version. Got: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 Expected: text/xml".
I have tried a lot of ways to solve this problem, but all were useless.
Here is my XML-configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services" 
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


 <context:component-scan base-package="com.soft.service"/>  

  <bean id="soapMessageFactory" 
       class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
     <property name="soapVersion">

  <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
     </property>
   </bean>


  <sws:annotation-driven/>  

   <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="myrequest"
      portTypeName = "myrequestPort"
      locationUri = "/ws/"   
      targetNamespace = "http://soft.com/namespace"
      createSoap11Binding="false"
      createSoap12Binding="true">           

      <sws:xsd location = "/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"/>  
   </sws:dynamic-wsdl>      

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decision of this problem! I have added initialization's parameter "messageFactoryBeanName" to the servlet "MessageDispatcherServlet" in the deployment descriptor web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>         
          <init-param> 
             <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
          </init-param>

          <init-param> 
             <param-name>messageFactoryBeanName</param-name>
             <param-value>soapMessageFactory</param-value>
          </init-param>
    </servlet>
```